# How to print very long (100000 items) array of integers to stdout

Tags: java, arrays, stdout

I'm trying to output some very long (100000 items) array of integers to stdout.

```
public int myPrint(int[] A) {
    System.out.println("A " + Arrays.toString(A));
}
```

It fails because stdout on the machine the code runs cuts the string from some point like (this is whole output, as you can see there is not 100000 items but much less):

```
A [-1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1
```

The code is remotely executed and I don't have option to change stdout formatting/buffer size etc. on the machine so it must be done inside the method.

Maybe I should split the string into sub strings?

Comment: What are you using to execute this? Windows command prompt?

Comment: You will probably have to insert your own return characters after so many characters.  This means you will end up calling println() multiple times or manipulating your string and inserting "\n" throughout.

Comment: can you write to a file?

Comment: What do you mean by "cuts the string"? If you're implying that System.out can't handle long strings, it would be a bug. How are you viewing the output?

Comment: >>"What do you mean by "cuts the string"<< I've edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Arrays.toString here. But output immediate values.
Maybe with extra flushing, as done with a println.

```
public int myPrint(int[] A) {
    System.out.print("A [");
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
         if (i % 25 == 0) {
             System.out.println(); // Or flush()
         }
         if (i != 0) {
             System.out.print(", ");
         }
         System.out.print(A[i];
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: Good point, I was so lazy that I didn't even think about solution like that, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

```
int width = 80;
int c = 0;
for(int i: A){
    String item = i + " ";
    c += item.length();
    System.out.print(c);

    if(c>width){
         System.out.println();
         c=0;
    }
}
```

Only prints 80 or so characters to the terminal before adding a new line.